# PHP substring row select mysql

Tags: php, mysql, substring

I like to substring the second row 'text2'from the mysql table.
Thanks!

```
    $sql = "select e.id, e.text1, e.text2, e.text3, count(r.id)     reportCount " . 
    "from employee e left join employee r on r.managerId = e.id " .
    "group by e.id order by e.text1, e.text2";

    try { ...
```

Comment: It's not really clear to me what the code in the first example has to do with the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gökhan, thanks for your help.
I've solved it:

```
select e.id, e.text1, (SUBSTRING(e.text2,1,30)) AS 'text2'
```

or with dots:

```
select e.id, e.text1,
    CASE 
    WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(e.text2) > 30 THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(e.text2, 1, 30), '...')
    ELSE e.text2
    END AS text2
```

Answer (score 0):

In select statement you can use case when clause

```
select e.id, e.text1, 
    CASE 
       WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(e.text2) >= 30 THEN 
         SUBSTR(e.text2,0,30) 
       ELSE 
         e.text2 
      END as text2,
    ....
```

I just wrote without test

Comment: if there are more then 30 characters, it cuts all

Comment: [check substr](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) and I updated my answer

Comment: i've changed substring to substr. same result